# Create another table just to store a few options?

Tags: mysql, database, performance

I'm creating a database with various tables. Let's take the user table, for example. It has fields such as marital status and system role. Each of those fields has predefined options. Does it make sense to create two new tables for each of those fields, so then when a user is added to the system, choices can be made available for selection e.g. single, married, divorced? It seems a bit of an overkill in terms of one extra query. Is this the best way to do it or do I have other options?

Comment: Can please let us know what are the predefined options for those two fields?

Comment: I haven't decided what they're called, but in either case it won't be more than 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ENUM datatype in MySQL to better take care of this scenario. Storing such options in a seperate table is a bad idea until you have a lot of them..

```
mysql> DESC Classes;
+-------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11)               | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| dept  | char(4)               | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| level | enum('Upper','Lower') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Classes;
+----+------+-------+
| id | dept | level |
+----+------+-------+
| 10 | MATH |       |
+----+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Classes VALUES (11, 'ENG', 'Upper')
    -> ;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM Classes;
+----+------+-------+
| id | dept | level |
+----+------+-------+
| 10 | MATH |       |
| 11 | ENG  | Upper |
+----+------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: So if one of the items needed to change and I renamed an ENUM value, would the previous entries keep the old value or is it smart enough to update? Does it store a key or the actual value?

Comment: If you seek to update a row data you can use a simple update query: `UPDATE table_name SET field = "value"`

Comment: Where `value` is one of the Enum options

Comment: So ENUM is basically just a way to get consistent input, but that value is stored just like a regular value, right?

Comment: If the value that you are trying to input is not one of the Enum values, the Insert operation will be successfull but the value will be blank

Comment: So, in the above case, if you try to add anything for the level field except `Upper` and `Lower`, it wont be added. If you are going to build an application, that will have only a few users Over-Normalization would be an overkill in this case..

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely create separate tables to store the available options for these various columns.  This is a good thing to do as far as normalization goes, and will also save you headaches down the road when you need to add, remove, disable or change any of the options.  Also, if don't create a separate table and populate the values directly in the user table, you may end up having to do something like `select distinct RelationshipStatus from User` to get the available options, which is not as performant as just selecting 10 or however many values from a separate table.

As someone commented, over-normalization can sometimes be a pain, but I've found that not normalizing something as a way to do a quick work-around almost always comes back to haunt you.

```
User
----
ID
RelationshipStatusId
...other columns


RelationshipStatus
------------------
ID
Value
Description
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree over-normalization can be bad, but under-normalization usually creates more headaches.

Comment: Please refer to my answer below. I guess under-normalization in this case won't trouble him much.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that extra tables are more of a pain to deal with when writing queries, but in your example, you're storing a code character, but then you mention wanting to map the character to a full description like `A - Administrator`.  If you need a mapping from a code character to a description like that, I think a separate table is the best way to go.  Also it's hard to guarantee that you'll never want to add more codes as you go, and then you have to keep track of what all the codes mean.

Comment: No I am not mapping. Few things like [M]arried, [D]ivoced don't need any description for a column like Marital Status. It is obvious. I am not creating any separate table. The DropDowns will display the full-text, but while storing he can store either single characters, if no further possibility is in mind. If any possibility like what I stated in my answer below, than your approach is good.

Answer (score 0):

For design's sake, create another table (what you don't want to do) with a proper PK. This will have the extra benefit of saving space, because imagine having 10000 registers with the word "married" on them.

Also, an alternative is using in your application a "dictionary", storing in a structure and Id and the value, like this:

```
Id   Marital Status
 1   Married
 2   Single
 ..  ......
```

The same table, but not in a database but in the application, hardcoded, serialized or in an external file.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the size of the rows also. It would be better option to split the tables in to multiple in terms of speed.
For ex. you can keep the frequent used columns in user table and all other informations/optional ones in separate tables. In this case you need take care while displaying the data also.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, there is no need for over-normalization as it will trouble you in writing queries. You need to take care of too many joins.

If your predefined conditions for Marital Status are: Married, Single and Divorced, I would just store a single character like: M, S and D and would provide these options in a DropDown with fixed values.

I think Marital Status has no further possibilities unless you think of something like:

Want to be Divorced

Married but living alone.

For user role also, I would do something like that:

A - Administrator
P - Power User
R - Restricted User
G - Guest

In case you need something more elaborate, I won't create further tables.